# Pyzbar: mime types and file extensions supported by pyzbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, zbar

I'm trying to use the pyzbar library to decode barcodes from a video in a project.I want to list down all the file extension and mime types supported by zbar/pyzbar.
I checked it's documentation and github repository https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar.
but didn't find much information about it.
can anybody help me to list down all the mime types and file extensions supported by pyzbar.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading [GitHub - NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar: Read one-dimensional barcodes and QR codes from Python 2 and 3. Example Usage](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar#example-usage) it looks like it is destined for working with files already processed into `PIL`'s `Image` or `numpy.ndarray` (loading done by `OpenCV`) or pixels data as bytes with eight bits-per-pixel. Therefore right question is *reading of which format is supported by PIL or OpenCV* (depending on which one you use).